# R: Read multiple sheets from a XLS file and rbind them with skip rows and setnames

Tags: r

I have multiple sheets in an excel file and I will like to row bind all of them into one single dataframe. The first sheet has 3 rows that I have to skip, which looks something like this.

```
unneededrow1
unneededrow2
unneededrow3
Date      Category       CatID       Revenue
1/1/2022  Shop           1           1203
1/1/2022  Online         2           3264
2/1/2022  Shop           1           1423
2/1/2022  Online         2           2464
```

For Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4, and and onwards, I have data without column names, which is something like the following.

```
3/1/2022  Shop           1           2454
3/1/2022  Online         2           4333
4/1/2022  Shop           1           2234
4/1/2022  Online         2           4565
```

My initial approach was to set colnames = FALSE for all sheets and rbind them but this result in mismatch of data types. I have looked up and tried other solutions but still couldn't achieve what I need. Appreciate any help here and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets have files e.g. `doc1.xlsx`, `doc2.xlsx`, `doc3.xlsx` and so on in the current working directory. Then you can the whole table like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

tibble(path = list.files(".", ".xlsx")) %>%
  mutate(
    has_header = path == "doc1.xlsx",
    data = path %>% map2(has_header, ~ {
      if (.y) {
        read_excel(.x, skip = 3)
      } else {
        read_excel(.x, col_names = c("Date", "Category", "CatID", "Revenue"))
      }
    })
  ) %>%
  pull(data) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

If you have multiple sheets in the same file you can do this instead:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

path <- "data.xlsx"
tibble(sheet = excel_sheets(path)) %>%
  mutate(
    has_header = sheet == "Sheet1",
    data = sheet %>% map2(has_header, ~ {
      if (.y) {
        read_excel(path, sheet = .x, skip = 3)
      } else {
        read_excel(path, sheet = .x, col_names = c("Date", "Category", "CatID", "Revenue"))
      }
    })
  ) %>%
  pull(data) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: Hi danloo. The second sheet onwards refers to Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4, and so on, are in the same excel file. They are not separate excel files.

Comment: @sushi4life I revised my answer

Answer (score 1):

Building up on @danloo's answer.

```
# Looping over files

# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

# Transforming answer above into a function
importFunction <- function(path = "your/filepath/and/filename.xls"){

test <-tibble(sheet = excel_sheets(path)) %>%
  mutate(
    has_header = sheet == "Sheet1",
    data = sheet %>% map2(has_header, ~ {
      if (.y) {
        read_excel(path, sheet = .x, skip = 3)
      } else {
        read_excel(path, sheet = .x, col_names = c("Date", "Category", "CatID", "Revenue"))
      }
    })
  ) %>%
  pull(data) %>%
  bind_rows()

return(test)

}

# Performing the loop 
# List all files in a directory containing some filename pattern
filesList <- list.files(path=".", pattern=".xls", all.files=TRUE, full.names=TRUE) # Remember to change pattern argument as you see fit

# Create empty dataframe to store files' data, by initialising it with column names tied to empty vectors
df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()), Category=character(), CatID=character(), Revenue=double(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Now we are gonna load every file in filesList
(for file in filesList)
{
dfFile = importFunction(file)
dfFile = as.data.frame(dfFile)
df = rbind(df, dfFile)
}

# Show df after loop
df.head()
```